# Interpreting results of PCA

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca

I've recently started an introductory machine learning course and the first topic we have covered is prinicpal component analysis (PCA) and overall I am finding the whole topic quite tricky to wrap my head around. I understand that the goal is to reduce the dimensionality of the data, but how we interpret results has me very confused. I will illustrate my confusion with an example and hopefully someone can explain it to me.

[image]

The biplot above is a result of the PCA I have carried out on some data about olive-oil. By looking at the PC loadings I am satisfied that using two principal components is justified (over 95% of the variability is accounted for). What exactly do these red lines indicate? What does it mean if a red line points in a particular direction? As mentioned previously, I have been told that we have carried out this PCA to reduce the dimensionality of the data, but what conclusions does this graph even suggest?

[image]

Here's the first PC loading (first principal component), I can see that the most important variables here are 'oleic', 'palmitic' and 'linoleic. What interpretation can we give to these.

I have tried to research this problem myself, but it feels like a lot of online resources don't really give a good idea of what our conclusion should be. So I ask, what can we take away from this PCA?

EDIT: The questions this post has been deemed to be 'too similar to' really aren't helping my understanding. I am coming from a place of not understanding how one interprets these at all, whereas the other posts seem to at least have some understanding. I could do with an explanation that is simple and less reliant on the mathematical side of things, and more explains things from an intuitive perspective.

Comment: Many more answers about interpreting PCA biplots can be found using the Search feature. Here's one to get you started: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+biplot+answers%3A1